# CSS background background solid colour issue with line-height

Tags: css

I am working on a design where I would like to have the background of text be as a block of text specific to the word themselves (As per example 1). When I decrease the leading. That is, make the line-height tighter and closer together it runs into issues and crops the letters above it.

Searching for a better approach so that I can have tight leading and a maintain the nice block background.

```css
.example1 {line-height: 1.4}
.example2 {line-height: 1.1}
.box { margin: 0 0 50px 0; padding: 0;  font-family: helvetica, arial; font-weight:bold;  font-size: 40px; width: 550px; }
.box > span { background-color: #060055; color: #ffffff; box-shadow: -10px 0px 0 10px #060055, 10px 0px 0 10px #060055, 0 0 0 10px #060055; box-decoration-break: clone; }
```

```html
<div class="box example1"><span>Testing anything<br> here. Testing anything here. <br>Testing anything here.</span></div>
<div class="box example2"><span>Testing anything<br> here. Testing anything here. <br>Testing anything here.</span></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add style `display: inline-block;` on span element.

Comment: Thank you so much Yudiz! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your text in another `<span>` and give it `position: relative;`.

**Edit:** Yudiz_Webdesign's solution is better, but I'll leave this here as an alternative.

```css
.example1 {line-height: 1.4}
.example2 {line-height: 1.1}
.box { margin: 0 0 50px 0; padding: 0;  font-family: helvetica, arial; font-weight:bold;  font-size: 40px; width: 550px; }
.box > span { background-color: #060055; color: #ffffff; box-shadow: -10px 0px 0 10px #060055, 10px 0px 0 10px #060055, 0 0 0 10px #060055; box-decoration-break: clone; }
.box span.inner { position: relative; }
```

```html
<div class="box example1"><span>Testing anything<br> here. Testing anything here. <br>Testing anything here.</span></div>
<div class="box example2"><span class="outer"><span class="inner">Testing anything<br> here. Testing anything here. <br>Testing anything here.</span></span></div>
```

Comment: Thank you ThingEvery. Much appreciated for your thoughts / insight.